# AngularJS - $HTTP Error request to Web Api End Point

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Question Background:**

I'm learning AngularJS and I'm attempting to make my first HTTP request using $HTTP.

**The Issue:**

I have a Web Api endpoint that is currently working fine with a non AngularJS app I have.

When I attempted to call the End Point through Angular with $http I get the following Errors in IE's console:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

localhost:55315
TypeError: Function expected
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:55315/Modules/Main.js:105:17)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:55315/Scripts/angular.min.js:95:194)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:55315/Scripts/angular.min.js:128:295)
   at m.prototype.$eval (http://localhost:55315/Scripts/angular.min.js:142:456)
   at m.prototype.$digest (http://localhost:55315/Scripts/angular.min.js:140:39)
   at m.prototype.$apply (http://localhost:55315/Scripts/angular.min.js:143:247)
   at g (http://localhost:55315/Scripts/angular.min.js:95:442)
   at x (http://localhost:55315/Scripts/angular.min.js:100:50)
   at e (http://localhost:55315/Scripts/angular.min.js:101:129)
```

**Code:**

*AngularJS:*

```
app.service('SearchService', function (Search, $http) {
var self = {

    searchList: [],
    loadSearchList: function () {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://thisistheurl.azurewebsites.net/api/ShoppingComparison/GetComparisons',
            data : {
                itemtosearch: 'rolex',
                itemIndex: 'watches',
                countryCode: 'UK',
                maxPrice: '50000',
                minPrice: '0',
                highToLow: true,
                lowToHigh: false,
                amazonEbay: true,
                amazonOnly: false,
                ebayOnly: false
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:55315/',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Passed"+ data + " " + status);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Failed" + data + " " + status);
        });

return self;
});
```

*Web Api End Point:*

```
  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public ViewItemModel GetComparisons(string itemToSearch, string itemIndex, string countryCode,
        string maxPrice, string minPrice, bool highToLow, bool lowToHigh, bool amazonEbay,
        bool amazonOnly, bool ebayOnly)
    {
        return _callAndSearchApis.SearchApis(itemToSearch, itemIndex, countryCode,
            maxPrice, minPrice, highToLow, lowToHigh, amazonEbay, amazonOnly, ebayOnly);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a `GET` method so you should be using `params` in place of `data`. Also you're missing a closing `}` after the `loadSearchList` definition.

And you could just do a `return { };` in place of `var self = {}`